# Lazy binary get

Tags: haskell, binary, lazy-evaluation

Why is [Data.Binary.Get](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/binary/0.7.0.1/doc/html/Data-Binary-Get.html) isn't lazy as it says? Or am I doing something wrong here?

```
import Data.ByteString.Lazy (pack)
import Data.Binary.Get (runGet, isEmpty, getWord8)

getWords = do
  empty <- isEmpty
  if empty
    then return []
    else do
      w <- getWord8
      ws <- getWords
      return $ w:ws

main = print $ take 10 $ runGet getWords $ pack $ repeat 1
```

This main function just hangs instead of printing 10 words.

Comment: The documentation you linked says: "This decoder has the downside that it will need to read all the input before it can return."

Comment: @MikhailGlushenkov Well indeed, how did I miss that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation you linked provides several examples. The first one needs to read all the input before it can return and looks a lot like what you have written. The second one is a left-fold and processes the input in a streaming fashion. Here's your code rewritten in this style:

```
module Main where

import Data.Word (Word8)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import Data.Binary.Get (runGetState, getWord8)

getWords :: BL.ByteString -> [Word8]
getWords input
   | BL.null input = []
   | otherwise =
      let (w, rest, _) = runGetState getWord8 input 0
      in w : getWords rest

main :: IO ()
main = print . take 10 . getWords . BL.pack . repeat $ 1
```

Testing:

```
*Main> :main
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```